# How can I use WordFrequencyData from Wolfram?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Here you can fetch word frequencies from Wolfram but I would like to know how to do this in Python because I am having difficulty finding any code to do this.
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordFrequencyData.html

Comment: The data comes from the Google Books English n-gram public dataset for which others have written various python code to access.  It is the data behind  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=python&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpython%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Wolfram Engine/Cloud, you can use the [Wolfram Client Library for Python](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/) to evaluate an expression using Wolfam's WordFrequencyData function in Python.